# EmEditorでマクロ処理をしたときに置換などの総数を全部表示、もしくはログ出力することは可能でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
EmEditorでマクロ処理をしたときに置換などの総数を全部表示、もしくはログ出力することは可能でしょうか？

数千行から数万行のマクロ記述のため毎度数十分かかるマクロ処理のため、何がどれぐらい重要な処理だったか記録を見たいというのがあります。

画面下に最後の処理の置換項目数などは表示されますが一連の過程全部を記録で何が何個変化したかなどのログ出力、表示です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Replace` メソッドの戻り値は、置換した文字列の数になります。
以下のようなマクロを記述すれば、結果をアウトプット バーに出力することができます。

```
OutputBar.Clear();
n = document.selection.Replace("a","b",eeReplaceAll,0);
OutputBar.writeln( "a replaced with b: " + n );

n = document.selection.Replace("c","d",eeReplaceAll,0);
OutputBar.writeln( "c replaced with d: " + n );

n = document.selection.Replace("e","f",eeReplaceAll,0);
OutputBar.writeln( "e replaced with f: " + n );

OutputBar.Visible = true;
OutputBar.SetFocus();
```

マクロを実行する方法は、以下の通りです。

上記のマクロを、適当なファイル名、例えば `ReplaceLog.jsee` という名前で保存します。
EmEditor の [マクロ] メニューの [選択] から、保存したマクロを選択します。
編集したいテキスト ファイルを開き、そのファイルがアクティブ状態で、[マクロ] メニューの [実行] (または <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) を選択します。すると、マクロが実行されます。